# ASP.NET Core 6 SignalR hub store data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, signalr, signalr-hub

I'm working on a simple chat using SignalR. At the moment I'm trying associate a users connection id with their identity user. I want to do this to prevent a user from impersonating another user by manually calling the hub functions.

My hub looks something like this:

```
public static class MessageContext
{
    public static string RECEIVE = "ReceiveMessage";
    public static string REGISTER = "Register";
    public static string SEND = "SendMessage";
}

public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public const string HUBURL = "/api/ChatSignal";
    Dictionary<string, string> _userContext;
    
    public ChatHub()
    {
        _userContext = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        var ConnectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
        var Username = Context.User.Identity.Name;
        _userContext.Add(ConnectionId, Username);
        Groups.AddToGroupAsync(ConnectionId, Username);
        return base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }
    
    public async Task SendAll(string user, string message)
    {
        var ConnectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
        message = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(message);
        await Clients.All.SendAsync(MessageContext.RECEIVE, _userContext[ConnectionId], message);
    }
    
    public Task SendMessage(string sender, string receiver, string message)
    {
        var ConnectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
        message = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(message);
        return Clients.Group(receiver).SendAsync(MessageContext.RECEIVE, _userContext[ConnectionId], message);
    }

    public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception e)
    {
        var ConnectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
        var Username = Context.User.Identity.Name;
        _userContext.Remove(ConnectionId);
        await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(e);
    }
}
```

My problem is that after when I call these functions, the dictionary gets set to null. After looking around for a while I found on MSDN that, hubs are "Transient", so each hub method call is executed on a new hub instance. This is a problem if I want to save `ConnectionId:Identity.Name`.

How can I use a dictionary to store this data for each hub instance?

Comment: Create a `singleton`-scoped service for storing data. Also, use a concurrent dictionary, since instance will be shared among all hubs

Answer (score 1):

To fix the null issue remove the initialization of `_userContext` in the constructor.

And change the line `Dictionary<string, string> _userContext;` -> `private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> _userContext = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();`

This is how your dictionary state will be retained across different hub instances. And `ConcurrentDictionary` will make it thread-safe.

But it is not a very scaleable solution. If you are really making a production-grade chat application, try to use something like `Redis Cache` for such state management.